# Combinatorics - Number of exactly one pair of double digits

Tags: combinatorics

For a $N$-digit string, where each digit can be from $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, M\}$, what is the probability that the string contains **exactly** one pair of double digits (not less and not more)?

For $N=4$ and $M\ge2$, examples of the searched strings (to be counted) are $1123$ or $2132$, but not $1112$ or $1122$.

Actually, I'm trying to figure out how many such sequences exist, since the having this, the probability computation is pretty straightforward.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must have $2\le N\le M+2$, since there are only $M+1$ "digits," which we should proably call "symbols," since digit is so strongly associated with the symbols $0$ to $9$.

To count the number of "good" strings, the doubled symbol can be chosen in $M+1$ ways. For each choice, the **locations** of the doubled symbol can be chosen in $\binom{N}{2}$ ways. For each such choice, the remaining symbols can be chosen in $\binom{M}{N-2}$ ways. And they can be permuted in $(N-2)!$ ways, for a count of
$$(M+1)\binom{N}{2}\binom{M}{N-2}(N-2)!.$$
The expression can be simplified in various ways.

The total number of strings is $(M+1)^N$. We are assuming all strings are equally likely, so for the probability we divide the number of good strings above by $(M+1)^N$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only thing is that we should have $N \le M+1$, since for $N=M+2$ there is for sure one pair.

Comment: I believe that is not right. Indeed if $N=M+2$ there is for sure some repetition. But there might be (and probably will be) multiple repetitions, and you had asked for the probability of one pair, not allowing triples, or quadruples, or several pairs.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the question asks for *exactly* one pair. And the formula give in the answer certainly gives 0 for $N \ge M + 2$.

Comment: @vonbrand: For $N=M+2$, the answer in my post is non-zero. The only term that "comes close" is the $\binom{M}{N-2}$ term, which is $1$ for $N=M+2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First consider which digit $n \in \{0,1,\ldots,M\}$ is doubled.  Then consider where the pair of $n$'s goes.  Finally, consider the possible values in all the other places.